# Meteor method returns different object on client and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a simple method, which should return all available methods on server back to client, but returned response is an empty object.

Client:

```
Meteor.call("servMethods", function(err, res) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  if(res) {
    console.log(res);
    // logs only:
    // Object {}
  }
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  "met1": function() {
  },
  "met2": function() {
  },
  "servMethods": function() {
    var methods = Meteor.default_server.method_handlers;
    console.log(methods);
    return methods;

    // logs correctly:
    // { met1: [Function: met1],
    //   met2: [Function: met2],
    //   servMethods: [Function: servMethods] }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server–side methods can only return EJSON–able values to the client. Functions are not EJSON-able, and therefore they're filtered out from the result object.

If you want to send the list of all available method *names* to the client, filter out the functions yourself, for example:

```
"servMethods": function() {
  return _.keys(Meteor.default_server.method_handlers);
},
```

Comment: Awesome, this should help me with writing future methods too. I was wondering if maybe it's a matter of asynchronous result from ...method_handler. I did check this code and now it works as expected, thanks.